# Server Error in '/' Application. Access to the path 'D:\FlashdataLabel\text.txt' is denied. in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Hi everyone i am trying to read the file into text from server i am facing the following error.Before publishing in the sever my program is working fine in visual studio after publishing i am facing that error in program

```
string constr6 = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["MSdbconnection"];
    string physicalPath = Server.MapPath(@"D:\FlashdataLabel\text.txt");
    File.WriteAllText(physicalPath, String.Empty);
    FileStream stream = new FileStream(physicalPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
    SqlConnection con6 = new SqlConnection(constr6);
    con6.ConnectionString = constr6;
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("  select PMax,VOC,ISC,VPM,IPM,PSV,AssignMSN,MSN_Mat,PSN from [LabelMSN]where PSN='" + txtpsn.Text + "'  order by id desc", con6);
    con6.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {

        writer.Write(reader["PMax"].ToString());
        writer.Write(",");
        writer.Write(reader["VOC"].ToString());
        writer.Write(",");
        writer.Write(reader["ISC"].ToString());
        writer.Write(",");
        writer.Write(reader["VPM"].ToString());
        writer.Write(",");
        writer.Write(reader["IPM"].ToString());
        writer.Write(",");
        writer.Write(reader["PSV"].ToString());
        writer.Write(",");
        writer.Write(reader["AssignMSN"].ToString());
        writer.Write(",");
        writer.Write(reader["MSN_Mat"].ToString());
        writer.Write(",");
        writer.Write(reader["PSN"].ToString());
        //writer.WriteLine();
   }
    reader.Close();
    writer.Close();
    stream.Close();
    con6.Close();


}
```

i am trying to write to a text file after publishing from server to local desktop i am getting error

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to insufficient access to this folder. Add the access with IIS_USR to this folder.